# Bluemix XSP return "File does not exist" when setting manifest with multiple databases

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I want to deploy multiple databases using the Bluemix XPages runtime.

In the `manifest.yml` file, I specified these database names:

> test1.nsf,application.nsf

I tried to git, deploy using designer,and use the REST API, but the result on console still looks the same:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed "XSP service" to "XPages runtime" based on the picture because Bluemix does not have an "XSP service."

Answer (score 1):

To do this would not actually require changes to the manifest file. Also, it isn't supported by the Bluemix tooling in Domino Designer, but it is still possible to do what you want.

Put simply, whatever you put into the "deployment directory" of your Bluemix app, will be deployed there. So if you want multiple NSF files to be deployed to Bluemix, then you need to make a copy of each NSF inside the deployment directory. Then deploy the application. (Designer does this copy step automatically during the deploy process for the NSF you have configured for Bluemix deployment, but as I say the tooling doesn't support multiple NSF deployment to a single Bluemix app.)

You can deploy with the Designer tooling or the CF CLI tool, but either way all your NSF files should be reachable on Bluemix after deployment and staging are complete.

You didn't make clear where in the manifest you were making changes, but seems you need to change it back so that only one NSF is listed in that setting. What's important here is the content of the deployment directory.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge: The Bluemix runtime takes ONE database that contains your application. Hence the runtime looks for a file `test1.nsf,application.nsf` which obviously doesn't exist.
It is the same patter as with other runtimes: e.g. you can't deploy 2 war files into a Websphere Liberty Java runtime.

My guess: the second database could work as a data source - you would need to configure it as a service (experimental in Bluemix) or host it on a Domino accessible to Bluemix.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure. In the documentation (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/xpages/index.html#xpruntime) there is an entry in APP_PRELOAD_DB section: "It can also be a comma-delimited list of filenames to accommodate the preloading of several NSF applications".